# Replacing indexes with unknown list size

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

How can I fill these index positions with an unknown size list?

For example if the list has 7 elements, how can I fill boardblanklis[winposition[X]] where X equals 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

I have included an example but it is for a list of 5 elements.
I need it for a list of unknown number of elements, defined by user input.
Probably need a loop.

```
for winposition in win:
    if boardblanklist[winposition[0]] == boardblanklist[winposition[1]] == boardblanklist[winposition[2]] == boardblanklist[winposition[3]] == boardblanklist[winposition[4]] == player:
        print('Congratulations! Player wins.')
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Try: `if all(boardblanklist[x] == player for x in winposition):`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @JackArmstrong do not forget to upvote and/or mark his answer as accpeted answer.

Comment: "How can I fill these index positions with an unknown size list?" It seems that what you *actually meant* was "how can I check that every element of the list is equal to a value?" It helps to ask the question you have a problem with, not the question relating to how you expect the solution to work.

Answer (score 1):

**Conditional**

```
if all(boardblanklist[x] == player for x in winposition):
```

**Full Usage**

```
for winposition in win:
    if all(boardblanklist[x] == player for x in winposition):
        print('Congratulations! Player wins.')
        sys.exit()
```

**Equivalent Code**

```
for winposition in win:
    test = True
    for x in winposition: # All elements in winposition
        if boardblanklist[x] != player:
            test = False
            break
    if test:
       print('Congratulations! Player wins.')
       sys.exit()
```